# RAID1 - Possible to recover failed drives?

Tags: raid, disaster-recovery, raid1, data-recovery, drac

PowerEdge 1850 has two physical hard drives, configured as RAID1.

Accessing via DRAC 4/I I can see that both drives indicate Failed & Offline.
However, the DRAC log indicates that both drives "de-asserted" from a failed state:

```
Severity   Date/Time   Description 
   Wed Jul 24 19:43:57 2013   Drive:Drive #1 de-asserted fault state 
   Wed Jul 24 19:43:57 2013   Drive:Drive #0 de-asserted fault state 
   Wed Jul 24 19:39:13 2013   Drive:Drive #0 asserted fault state 
   Sun Jun 30 09:35:31 2013   Drive:Drive #1 asserted fault state
```

Bootup message indicates:

> Configuration of NVRAM and drives mismatch for :-  HA-0(Normal
>   mismatch)

**Can these drives/data be recovered?**

In DRAC menu, what does "Rebuild" do vs. "Initialize"?

Comment: What if you connect those drives to a normal sata controller? In picked drives from Dell servers before (MegaRAID controllers) and the drive meta data was not stored at the start, so you could still and mount see the disk. Then, you can use `dd_rescue`

Comment: Halfgaar: Good idea connecting to a SATA controller. The server is out-of-state now, but if I have it sent back that might be an option. Otherwise, there is no option to touch the hardware.

Comment: > "Rebuild" vs. "Initialize". I think Initialize wipes the disk and Rebuild attempts to load data to it from one of the array's working drives. ?

Comment: Replace the drives, restore from backup, get on with life...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild: Rebuild will regain the redundancy by copying data from one disk to another in RAID 1 and calculating the parity in case of a RAID 5.

Initialize: Initialization is the process of zero filling your HDD which will remove the data of those sectors. Based on the type it may write zeros to all the sector(Slow Initialize) or will be writing zeros only to the first few sectors of the disks(Fast initialize).